# SQL query return List

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, winforms, visual-studio

I can't seem to get this working:

My table column headers are 'genre' 'artist' 'album'
and the params I'm passing in are (type, filter, value) ("artist", "genre", "Rock") where there are two rows in the db with "Rock" for the genre.

When I follow the debugger, the 'while (reader.Read())' must return false because the loop is never entered and thus nothing written to the List.

```
    public static List<String> getWithFilter(String type, String filter, String value)
    {

        List<String> columnData = new List<String>();

        string query = "SELECT @type FROM Music WHERE" +
            " @filter = '@value'";
        SqlConnection connection = Database.GetConnection();
        SqlCommand getData = new SqlCommand(query, connection);
        getData.Parameters.AddWithValue("@type", type);
        getData.Parameters.AddWithValue("@filter", filter);
        getData.Parameters.AddWithValue("@value", value);
        connection.Open();

        using (connection)
        {
            using (getData)
            {
                using (SqlDataReader reader = getData.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        columnData.Add(reader.GetString(0));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return columnData;
    }
```

Comment: Your query is a bit of a mess - you can't use parameters the way you're using them.  Can you explain what you're trying to query for?  Please also show your table structure, parameters you're passing, and desired output.

Comment: You cannot use parameters for the names of columns and you don't put quotes around them when using them.  You'll have to actually build the query  like `"SELECT " + type + " FROM... WHERE " + filter + " = @value";`

Comment: It's good that you use SQL parameters, but `type` and `filter` cannot be parameters since they represent column names as I understand.

Comment: After the params are added the query executed is:

SELECT artist FROM Music WHERE genre = 'Rock'

Comment: Are you sure? IF it is possible to use parameter this way (I am not sure) the select would look like `select 'artist' from music where 'genre' = ''Rock'' `.

Comment: @CraigHalloway No, the way you wrote it the query executed is `SELECT 'artist' FROM Music WHERE 'genre' = 'Rock'`. Note the single quotes around "artist` and "genre" which turns them to a string literals. And of course the `WHERE` condition is never met.

Comment: @juharr Why don't you compose an answer so we clean up this question :)

Comment: @IvanStoev Actually I believe it's `'genre' = '@value'` since they have redundant quotes around the last parameter.

Comment: @juharr Ah, of course. Yet another reason to post an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use parameters for the names of columns and you don't put quotes around them when using them.  Right now your query is the equivalent of

```
SELECT 'artist' FROM Music WHERE 'genre' = '@value'
```

You can do the following instead.

```
string query = "SELECT " + type + " FROM Music WHERE " + filter + " = @value";
```

And just remove the lines that create the `@type` and `@fitler` parameters.

Comment: Would't this be vulnerable to a SQL injection attack?

Comment: @maccettura Only if `type` and or `filter` are user inputs.  If they are then the OP should check them against a list of valid column names first.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking either for *formatting* or *string interpolation* (requires C# 6.0):

```
string query = 
   $@"SELECT {type} 
        FROM Music 
       WHERE {filter} = @value";

... 

getData.Parameters.AddWithValue("@value", value);
```

Formatting is a bit more wordy:

```
 string query = String.Format(
    @"SELECT {0} 
        FROM Music 
       WHERE {1} = @value", type, filter);
```

Answer (score 0):

I assuming that you're using .net 2

```
DateTime current = DateTime.Now;
       Console.WriteLine(current);
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
        string q = "SELECT @field FROM student";
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(q, conn);
        da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@field", "snName");
        DataTable dt = new System.Data.DataTable();
        conn.Open();
        da.Fill(dt);
        conn.Close();
        List<string> names = new List<string>();
        foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
        {
            names.Add(dr[0].ToString());
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Fetching {0} data for {1}", names.Count, DateTime.Now - current);
        Console.ReadKey();
```

You can use lambda expression to mapping the datatable in .net >4